# Removing Black Edge in Aerial Imagery using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, aerial-photography

How do I remove the black edge in image below on a raster aerial imagery?

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

[image]

Comment: If you were a GDAL user you could pre-process your image, that I guess is JPEG compressed, with the nearblack utility https://gdal.org/programs/nearblack.html. With ESRI tools you can try these  tricks https://community.esri.com/t5/data-management-questions/remove-near-black-edges-off-some-rasters/td-p/465652.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this:-

This works for a mosaic dataset, so kindly test if this can resolve your concern.

1. In the Catalog pane, right-click the mosaic dataset > Modify > Build Footprints
2. In the Build Footprints tool, leave the Query Definition blank and select Radiometry under Computation Method
3. Change the Minimum and Maximum Data Value settings so that they exclude the border values. For example, if there are black borders with pixel values of 1, change the Minimum Data Value to 2; if there are white borders with pixel values of 255, change the Maximum Data Value to 254
4. Leave the rest of the settings at the default and click OK
5. Right-click the mosaic dataset in Catalog > Optimize > Build Overviews. Leave the defaults and click OK

Related Links:-

[Build Overviews (Data Management)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/build-overviews.htm)

[Build Footprints (Data Management)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/build-footprints.htm)